# Spacy, matcher with entities spanning more than a single token

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am trying to create a matcher that finds negated custom entities in the text. It is working fine for entities that span a single token, but I am having trouble trying to capture entities that span more than one token.

As an example, let's say that my custom entities are animals (and are labeled as `token.ent_type_ = "animal"`)

`["cat", "dog", "artic fox"]` (note that the last entity has two words).

Now I want to find those entities in the text but negated, so I can create a simple matcher with the following pattern:

`[{'lower': 'no'}, {'ENT_TYPE': {'REGEX': 'animal', 'OP': '+'}}]`

And for example, I have the following text:

`There is no cat in the house and no artic fox in the basement`

I can successfully capture `no cat` and `no artic`, but the last match is incorrect as the full match should be `no artic fox`. This is due to the `OP: '+'` in the pattern that matches a single custom entity instead of two. How can I modify the pattern to prioritize longer matches over shorter ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to use the [doc retokenize method](https://spacy.io/api/doc#retokenize) in order to merge the individual tokens of each multi-token entity into a single token:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', parse=True, tag=True, entity=True)

animal = ["cat", "dog", "artic fox"]
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
for a in animal:
    ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "animal", "pattern": a}])
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)


doc = nlp("There is no cat in the house and no artic fox in the basement")

with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end])


from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern =[{'lower': 'no'},{'ENT_TYPE': {'REGEX': 'animal', 'OP': '+'}}]
matcher.add('negated animal', None, pattern)
matches = matcher(doc)


for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span)
```

the output is now:

> no cat
>   no artic fox

Comment: With this solution I don't even need to add `...{'OP': '+'}` to the custom entity