# Add multiple EntityRuler with spaCy (ValueError: 'entity_ruler' already exists in pipeline)

Tags: python, spacy

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477852/spacy-matcher-with-entities-spanning-more-than-a-single-token) shows how to add custom entity rule where the entities span more than one token. The code to do that is below:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', parse=True, tag=True, entity=True)

animal = ["cat", "dog", "artic fox"]
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
for a in animal:
    ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "animal", "pattern": a}])
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp("There is no cat in the house and no artic fox in the basement")

with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for ent in doc.ents:
        retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end])
```

I tried to add another custom entity ruler as follows:

```
flower = ["rose", "tulip", "african daisy"]
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
for f in flower:
    ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "flower", "pattern": f}])
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
```

but I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-702f460a866f> in <module>()
      4 for f in flower:
      5     ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "flower", "pattern": f}])
----> 6 nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
      7 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py in add_pipe(self, component, name, before, after, first, last)
    296                 name = repr(component)
    297         if name in self.pipe_names:
--> 298             raise ValueError(Errors.E007.format(name=name, opts=self.pipe_names))
    299         if sum([bool(before), bool(after), bool(first), bool(last)]) >= 2:
    300             raise ValueError(Errors.E006)

ValueError: [E007] 'entity_ruler' already exists in pipeline. Existing names: ['tagger', 'parser', 'ner', 'entity_ruler']
```

My questions are:

1. How can I add another custom entity ruler?
2. Is it a best practice to use capital letters for the label (for example, instead of `ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "animal", "pattern": a}])` one should use `ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "ANIMAL", "pattern": a}])` instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add another custom entity ruler to your pipeline by changing its name (to avoid name collision). Here is some code to illustrate, but please read the remark below:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable = ['ner'])
rulerPlants = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
flowers = ["rose", "tulip", "african daisy"]
for f in flowers:
    rulerPlants.add_patterns([{"label": "flower", "pattern": f}])
animals = ["cat", "dog", "artic fox"]
rulerAnimals = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
for a in animals:
    rulerAnimals.add_patterns([{"label": "animal", "pattern": a}])

rulerPlants.name = 'rulerPlants'
rulerAnimals.name = 'rulerAnimals'
nlp.add_pipe(rulerPlants)
nlp.add_pipe(rulerAnimals)

doc = nlp("cat and artic fox, plant african daisy")
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text , '->', ent.label_)

#output:
#cat -> animal
#artic fox -> animal
#african daisy -> flower
```

We can verify that the pipeline does contain both entity rulers:

```
print(nlp.pipe_names)
# ['tagger', 'parser', 'rulerPlants', 'rulerAnimals']
```

Remark: I would suggest using the simpler and more natural approach of making a new entity ruler which contains the rules of both entity rulers:

```
rulerAll = EntityRuler(nlp)
rulerAll.add_patterns(rulerAnimals.patterns)
rulerAll.add_patterns(rulerPlants.patterns)
```

Finally concerning your question about best practices for entity labels, it is a common practice to use abbreviations written with capital letters (see [Spacy NER documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities))
for example ORG, LOC, PERSON, etc..

Edits following questions:

1)If you do not need Spacy's default Named Entity Recognition (NER), then I would suggest disabling it as that will speedup computations and avoid interference (see discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536896/custom-entity-ruler-with-spacy-did-not-return-a-match/57545416)). Disabling NER will not cause unexpected downstream results (your document just won't be tagged for the default entities LOC, ORG, PERSON etc..).

2)There is this idea in programming that "*Simple* is better than *complex*." ([see here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)). There can be some subjectivity as to what constitutes a *simpler* solution. I would think that a processing pipeline with fewer components is *simpler* (i.e. the pipeline containing both entity rulers would seem more *complex* to me). However depending on your needs in terms of profiling, adjustability etc.. It might be *simpler* for you have several different entity rulers as described in the first part of this solution. It would be nice to get the author's of Spacy to give their view on these two different design choices.

3) Naturally, the single entity ruler above can be directly created as follows:

```
rulerAll = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
for f in flowers:
    rulerAll.add_patterns([{"label": "flower", "pattern": f}])
for a in animals:
    rulerAll.add_patterns([{"label": "animal", "pattern": a}])
```

The other code above shown for constructing rulerAll is meant to illustrate how we can query an entity ruler for the list of patterns which have been added to it. In practice we would construct rulerAll directly without first constructing rulerPlant and rulerAnimal. Unless we wanted to test and profile these (rulerPlant and rulerAnimal) individually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @DBaker! Would you mind elaborating on why you had the option `disable = ['ner']` in your code? Would that cause any unexpected results downstream. I omitted that option and your code still works, so when is it necessary/essential that we use the option `disable = ['ner']`? Also, why did you say it would be _simpler_ and more natural to use `rulerAll`? I thought that would be more complex in that we had to first created `rulerAnimals` and `rulerPlants` before we wrote _additional_ 3 lines of code for `rulerAll`?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Nemo, I am glad that I could help. I have added an edit to the answer in order to clarify the points which mentioned in your comment

Comment: Love your added edits which give me more food for thought (particularly the last sentence of point 2 about the SpaCy author's view). Thank you!