# how can I pass table or dataframe instead of text with entity recognition using spacy

Tags: python, pandas, entity, spacy, named-entity-recognition

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546292/12496869) shows how to add multiple EntityRuler with spaCy. The code to do that is below:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable = ['ner'])
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")


flowers = ["rose", "tulip", "african daisy"]
for f in flowers:
    ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "flower", "pattern": f}])
animals = ["cat", "dog", "artic fox"]
for a in animals:
    ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "animal", "pattern": a}])



result={}
doc = nlp("cat and artic fox, plant african daisy")
for ent in doc.ents:
        result[ent.label_]=ent.text
df = pd.DataFrame([result])
print(df)
```

**The output:**

```
      animal         flower
0  artic fox  african daisy
```

**The problem is**: How can i pass *dataframe or table* instead of the text:**"cat and artic fox, plant african daisy"**

Comment: You can't. You need to write a function to get the text out of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that your dataframe is

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text':["cat and artic fox, plant african daisy"]})
```

You may define a custom method to extract the entities and then use it with [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```py
def get_entities(x):
    result = {}
    doc = nlp(x)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        result[ent.label_]=ent.text
    return result
```

and then

```py
df['Matches'] = df['Text'].apply(get_entities)
>>> df['Matches']
0    {'animal': 'artic fox', 'flower': 'african daisy'}
Name: Matches, dtype: object
```