# How to remove/add entities in a custom entity ruler in spaCy 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, spacy-3

I have a custom **entity ruler** added to the spacy **"en_core_web_sm"** model. I want to add or remove entities in it when needed. This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554459/19569601), however I believe that is not correct as the person is talking about the **ner** component not the entity ruler. 
Short version of that answer is that Spacy tends to forget previous patterns when you add new ones. 
 However that only happens when you are training the model's **ner** compenent with examples. **Entity ruler** is not trained on examples, it is simply given the patterns and labels to match and it has worked for me perfectly (I added it after the **parser** component).
 If I'm wrong please correct me and if I'm right then how do I **add/delete** entities in the **entity ruler** (patterns and labels both or separately, whatever is possible).

```
def custom_ruler(file_path):
    ruler = nlp.add_pipe('entity_ruler', after='parser')
    ruler.from_disk(file_path)
```

This function is given a jsonl file that contains the entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items to the entity ruler as usual.

```
ruler = nlp.get_pipe("entity_ruler")
patterns = ... whatever your patterns are ...
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
```

See the [Entity Ruler docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler). See the [API docs](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler#remove) for examples of removal.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Polm stated, you can add your own rule-based patterns to overwrite the model. To do this, just create a list of dictionaries that have two pairs:

- `pattern` defines what exactly it should overwrite;
- `label`defines what label to give to the entity instead.
  When you add those patterns to your ruler with `add_patterns()` method, the `nlp` Doc object gets automatically updated, and you could enumerate through its named entities and see the corrections in play.

```py
    #Patterns is a list of dictionaries of the token text and the expected label.
    patterns = [{"label": "NATION", "pattern": "Maya"}, 
        {"label": "NATION", "pattern": "Aztecs"},
        {"label": "DATE", "pattern": "BCE"}]
    #Ruler is the English entity recogniser.
    ruler = english.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")
    ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
    #We can now see the new entities in the text.
    chocolate = english(source)
    for entity in chocolate.ents:
        print(entity.text, entity.label_)
```

You can learn more about the spaCy NLP library from [my showcasing notebook](https://github.com/ChocolateMagnate/linguistic-research/blob/main/Showcase/_spacy.ipynb) or take a look at [this Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIUTsFT2MeQ).
[image: What I got]