# spacy 3 train custom ner model

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I tried to train datasets :

[('text data text data text data text data text data text data text data text data.',
{'entities': [(7, 19, 'PERSON'), (89, 91, 'PERSON'), (98, 101, 'PERSON')]}),
('"text data text data text data text data text data text data text data text data text data text data text data text data.',
{'entities': [(119, 137, 'PERSON')]}),]

```
n_iter = 8
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
    for _s, _e, label in annotations.get('entities', []) :
        print('Adding label - "', label, '"')
        ner.add_label(label)

from spacy.training.example import Example
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding

other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes): 
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for itn in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        for batch in spacy.util.minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001)):
            for text, annotations in batch:
                doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
                example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
                nlp.update([example], drop=0.35,losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
            print('losses -', losses)
```

The result was
losses - {}

till so many iterations

Does anyone know which one is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually added the NER component to your pipeline. Replace `nlp.create_pipe` with:

```py
ner = nlp.add_pipe("ner")
```

(Be aware that you're training on individual examples rather than batches of examples in this setup, so the batching code isn't doing anything useful. Have a look at the [NER demo projects](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines) for more examples of how to do this with the train CLI, which has a more flexible and optimized training loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can both initialize and add the components using[`add_pipe`](https://spacy.io/api/language#add_pipe) method in spacy 3.X. This is discussed in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906945/valueerror-nlp-add-pipe-now-takes-the-string-name-of-the-registered-component-f) as well.